# Eclipse debugger does not show call stack

Tags: eclipse, debugging, callstack

How is it possible for Eclipse debugger not to show call stack? I have a breakpoint and when it stops on it, I have only that function in the stack, being unable to see who called it.

I have

`Default suspend policy for new breakpoints` = `Suspend VM`

and

`Show monitors` = `ON`

Eclipse is Helios SR2

Comment: Sounds odd, can you add a screen shot of the `Debug` view?

Comment: Sorry forgot to make a screenshot.

Comment: Did you check debug perspective? See picture in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19694447/run-to-the-next-breakpoint-in-eclipse-java