# Run to the next breakpoint in Eclipse (java)

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

How to run to the next breakpoint in Eclipse? I stopped at a breakpoint, after that I need to just run through some long piece of code until the next breakpoint is hit. 
I searched SO and Eclipse but did not find the answer.
Just having nightmare with the Eclipse debugger (still can't forget my beloved Sun Workshop which I can't praise high enough)...

Comment: Don't you just press "play"? Are you in the debug screen?

Comment: @FredLarson F5 is a single step forward AFAIK. The green button.

Comment: Continue/F8. http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html#usedebug_control

Comment: Thanks everybody! After I found out there is no "jump" in Eclipse, I keep asking stupid questions about it...

Comment: Why downvote? Is it obvious, not suitable for SO, or you just in bad mood?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The button that looks like the play button on a tv remote.

Comment: The button which marked Resume? I'm asking because I checked but not sure about the result :) (exception)

Comment: This isn't entirely true is it? Which green button?

Comment: The button with a green triangle an a yellow bar to the left of the triangle. Kind of like this `|>`

Answer (score 31):

The green button, or <kbd>F8</kbd> will continue a suspended execution due to a breakpoint. You can optionally switch to the debug perspective to see the default set of views that are useful for debugging. The green button in a circle(right above the "continue" label in the image) will *not* suffice.

```
|====|  ====8
|    |  |    88
|    |  |      88
|    |  |        88
|    |  |      88
|    |  |    88
|====|  ====8
```

[image: debug perspective screenshot with labels]

Comment: Thanks! Is it debug perspective picture? (mine is slightly different)

Comment: Nice Description +1 :)

Answer (score 5):

Press f8

-or -

hit the button in debug toolbar that looks like this

[image: resume button]

-or-

-go to Run -> Resume

Answer (score 2):

When you're debugging you should be on the Debugging screen as it has all the windows interesting for debugging. If you're there you should see some controls like a play/resume, pause/suspend and stop/terminate. You can proceed to the next break point by pressing the resume(play) button or press F8.

It is *not* true that you just hit play. If you're on the Java window pressing play, or as put "the green button" runs the program again without debugging it. If you like to use the buttons, ensure you're on the correct window.

Comment: @TT_: At some point in time you were asked if you wanted to auto switch when debugging starts with the option of remembering that decision; perhaps you said "remember, no"?